# Jest snapshot tests failing with same output because of ANSI

Tags: typescript, jestjs, snapshot, ts-jest, ansi-escape

So, I created a custom jest matchers and one of the ways I tests them is by using snapshots testing.

The tests passed in my local environment (Windows) and failed in the CI (Linux)

The output for the failing tests was identical.

I tried to recreate the problem so I ran the test in my WSL and the tests passed, so I run it on some other Linux server and the tests passed again.

I thought it was some kind of line ending problems so I checked and my line ending are LF so still no solution.

I debugged the CI by:

- Printing the snapshot
- Update the snapshot
- Print again

I found out that my snapshots contained ANSI escape codes, so after some searching I found this GitHub issue comment - [Snapshot comparison failing but results look identical](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9865#issuecomment-618680506) where the collaborator wrote:

> You can try running with  `NO_COLOR=1` or `CI=true` or some such

So I tried both at the same time in my local machine and no luck, I tried it in the WSL and it failed, so than I removed the `CI=true` (because I thought about the ANSI) and the tests passed, so I tried only with `CI=true` and the tests failed.

So I don’t wanna run my tests only in WSL so I need to find a different solution for it to be the same snapshots.

Comment: the `snapshotSerializers` is the preferred approach as it is cross machines and the proper way to handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was to use [`jest-snapshot-serializer-ansi`](https://github.com/ikatyang/jest-snapshot-serializer-ansi) package.

I needed to add it to the `snapshotSerializers` in the jest config like that:

```json
{
  "snapshotSerializers": ["jest-snapshot-serializer-ansi"]
}
```